# Script tag breaking my html document?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, filepath

I am currently writing out a HTML document, and I'm trying to include Bootstrap's Js file. However, each time I try to do so, it will just make my page appear blank white. I know it is something to do with the head of the document, but i'm unsure why this is happening...

So I viewed the source code via chrome, and I get this (click image to enlarge)

[image]

So when I remove the Bootstrap.js link It goes back to normal, content reappears again, like this. (click to enlarge)

[image]

By me saying content not showing and reappearing, I literally mean the visual side upon previewing.

Comment: It would be very helpful and more convenient to see your code posted here on SO instead of a link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"/>
```

`<script>` tags don't support auto-closing. Use this instead:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Remember that the bootstrap.js file also requires that you put jquery so its a good idea to out the jquery script and then the bootstrap script for the bootstrap javascript to work.